# How to fix: "Cannot find field: canvasContext in message google.actions.v2.Input" in Google Actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Invoking my Google action produces inconsistent results. Sometimes it'll work normally, and sometimes it'll just say "app isn't responding right now. Try again later."

When it doesn't respond, the error in Stackdriver logs states:

`MalformedResponse: ErrorId: 9d77f434-ed3c-485b-9531-05449ee83c29. Failed to parse json into AppRequest proto. com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Cannot find field: canvasContext in message google.actions.v2.Input`

This error has happened on the google home, google home mini, and the Lenovo smart display. It happens most on the smart display. And it hasn't happened yet on a mobile device.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I suggest you add a pertinent code snippet to assist others assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see exactly the same error in some of our customer projects. For me it looks like a Google hiccup because our AoGs with that error in the logs does not even use Canvas.

Comment: It really does seem like a hiccup as some other production apps on the store also occasionally went unresponsive.

The issue also seems to have stopped out of the blue the very next day. I'm really curious to find out what caused a request for something called "canvasContext." I'm also a little paranoid that the issue will surface again.